# SQL PreparedStatement & autocommit

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, autocommit

If I create a preparedstatement using a JDBC connection which has "autocommit off", do I need to call commit() to make the transaction permanent or only the prepare call is enough? Note that I only want to prepare a statement and keep it for later execution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is: yes you have to call commit.

The "prepare" step does not do anything that is relevant for transaction handling on the server.

You have to call `executeUpdate()` (or `execute()`) to start a transaction (assuming the used SQL does in fact start a transaction)

Using a PreparedStatement without auto-commit requires the following steps:

1. Prepare the statement
2. Set the parameter values
3. call `executeUpdate()` (or `execute()` depending on the type of statement)
4. call `Connection.commit()`

To make things clearer: calling `prepareStatement()` does **not** require a `commit()`.

Comment: Actually, I have several CRUD SQL statements and I want to have them ready as preparedstatements when I initialize the connection objects (of connectionpool). Later on my application can execute those preparedstatements by setting appropriate parameters and certainly calling commit() when needed. So I wanted to know if I need to call commit after just the prepare call but if I understand you correctly, preparing doesn't do anything on the server until I call execute?

Comment: @AliM: That doesn't change anything regarding the need to call `executeUpdate()` and `commit()`

Comment: did you get the last part of my previous post? so you answer still holds true for that?

Comment: @AliM: which "previous post"? **Preparing** a statement does **not** require a commit.

Comment: no problem.. I got the answer!
To make things clearer: calling prepareStatement() does not require a commit().

Comment: Actually, a lot of the time a prepare does do things on the server (eg parse the statement and return type info to the client), just not things that need to be committed

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: yes, you are absolutely correct. I just wanted to keep this simple for the sake of the discussion.

Comment: So, why do we need to commit if execute actually executes the query? Thanks

Comment: While I am updating the database with the help of prepared statement, expecting to commit though I have not set auto-commit to false. This is happening for postgresql. Any reason for this?